# VBA - How to get workbook filepath/location if macro is run from Personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, save-as, vba

I've got my macros tucked away in my Personal.xlsb file, and I would like to save a file in the same directory as the workbook I'm applying the macro to.
Currently when I use:

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Its getting the location of Personal.xlsb (where the macro stems from) and not the workbook's directory. Can someone please tell me how I can fix this (without adding a module to my workbook)?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Path` will give the path of the workbook that is active.  If you show your code, we can help you decide whether that is the appropriate thing to use, or whether it is some other workbook object you need to use the `Path` property on.

Comment: @YowE3K Perfect, thanks! That was what I needed, just something to locate the workbook I was working on instead of the one where the macro came from, thanks again so much! :D Issue is resolved!

Comment: @YowE3K please fill an answer, so that question may be marked as answered.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Path` property can be used on any `Workbook` object, not just on the `ThisWorkbook` one.

So, to obtain the path of the `ActiveWorkbook`, you can use `ActiveWorkbook.Path`.

Or if you have, for instance, opened a workbook using something like:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test\File1.xlsx")
```

then you can use `wb.Path` which would, of course, return `"C:\Temp\Test"`.

Comment: cheers! in my case its just to run a macro on several files in misc places and have it spit out a csv file in the same directory hence the need for a dynamic solution :)